# How to copy values that have just been deleted into 'Archive' Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-dates

Setting up so any expired date rows get deleted. But I would Like to **Delete and Move to `Archive` tab** (sheet).

Have tried taking other codes and integrating but cannot find the code.

```
function DeleteOldEntries() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Current'); // assumes Current is the name of the sheet
  var datarange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var lastrow = datarange.getLastRow();
  var values = datarange.getValues(); // get all data in a 2D array
  var currentDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // tomorrow
  for (var i = lastrow; i >= 2; i--) {
    var tempDate = values[i - 1][1]; // arrays are 0 indexed so row1 = values[0] and col3 = [2]
    if (tempDate != NaN && tempDate <= currentDate) {
      sheet.deleteRow(i);
    } // closes if
  } // closes for loop
} // closes function
```

Comment: What does it mean 'move'? You want to activate a range or to move the data?

Comment: Take the row that is being deleted and add it into archive.

Comment: Welcome. As per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well -. ([Why vote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
// As used at: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/133308/
function DeleteOldEntries() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Current'); // assumes Current is the name of the sheet

  var archive = ss.getSheetByName('Archive');

  var datarange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var lastrow = datarange.getLastRow();
  var values = datarange.getValues(); // get all data in a 2D array
  var currentDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // tomorrow
  for (var i = lastrow; i >= 2; i--) {
    var tempDate = values[i - 1][1]; // arrays are 0 indexed so row1 = values[0] and col3 = [2]
    if (tempDate != NaN && tempDate <= currentDate) {

      archive.appendRow(values[i - 1]);

      sheet.deleteRow(i);
    } // closes if
  } // closes for loop
} // closes function
```

In other ways you can adopt the next snippet. This removes all rows which contains 'asdf' in *B-column*. All data is archived.

```
// As mentioned at: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/133308/
function deleteRowsByConditional_(sheet, condition, action) {
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  values.unshift([]);
  values.reverse().forEach(
    function() {
      var i = this.l - arguments[1];
      if (this.condition.apply(null, [arguments[0], i, arguments[2]])) {
        this.isContinue++;
      } else if (this.isContinue) {
        if (action) action(arguments[2], i, this.isContinue);
        this.sheet.deleteRows(i, this.isContinue);
        this.isContinue = 0;
      }
    },
    { sheet: sheet, condition: condition, isContinue: 0, l: values.length }
  );
}

function run2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var archive = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Archive');

  var action = function(values, i, i2) {
    var data = values.slice(values.length - i - i2, values.length - i);
    archive
      .getRange(archive.getLastRow() + 1, 1, data.length, data[0].length)
      .setValues(data);
  };

  var condition = function(row) {
    return row[1] === 'asdf';
  };

  deleteRowsByConditional_(sheet, condition, action);
}
```

Full code is [here](https://github.com/oshliaer/google-apps-script-snippets/blob/master/snippets/spreadsheet_delete-rows-by-conditional/delete-rows-by-conditional.js)

Comment: I got the script by googling "Delete expired rows in google sheets" somewhere. I am not a programmer but tuned it a bit to my knowledge and it worked. I appreciate the answer, tried your first script and it works exactly like I want it! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @marikamitsos. Some snippets already have this. See https://github.com/oshliaer/google-apps-script-snippets/blob/master/snippets/spreadsheet_insert-rows-before-by-condition/insert-rows-before-by-condition.js I am currently trying to iterate over this repository and update it for ease of use.

Comment: @user226383 if this solves you problem I think it can be marked as 'best'.

Comment: @marikamitsos be free to do good things with me =)

Comment: @marikamitsos https://github.com/oshliaer/google-apps-script-snippets/blob/master/snippets/spreadsheet_delete-rows-by-conditional/delete-rows-by-conditional.js

Comment: @contributorpw That is really useful.